# Passing in Id for each data item in bar chart using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Currently i have my bar chart displaying a bar chart graph and for each bar the title and the data value is shown with no problem. But i would also like to add the id for each displayed bar because i have the bars clickable and with a click on a bar i would like to pass in the id of that individual bar so i can display page with another set of graphs particular to the item id that was passed in.

This is an example of the current json data that i am using to create my chart:

Array:...

```
{id: 1, uuid: "0ff158d7-09a7-41df-81d1-fd3ac752a967", name: "Example 1", percentage: 34}

{id: 2, uuid: "81aa6eb2-b6fe-4d14-a3ea-f5487b67784a", name: "Example 2", percentage: 0}

{id: 7, uuid: "b7d7fd90-d9af-4a56-aceb-20bfdeda3af4", name: "Example 3", percentage: 12}
....
```

This is how i am populating my chart:

```
var value: Array<any> = [];
  var name: Array<any> = [];
  var ids: Array<any> = [];
  this.myService.getData(url).subscribe(
      data => {
          this.results = data;
          this.results.map(function(result){
              value.push(result.percentage);
              name.push(result.name);
              ids.push(result.id);
          })
          this.chart = {
              title: {
                  text: '',
                  style: {
                      display: 'none'
                  }
              },
              credits: {
                  enabled: false
              },
              chart: {
                  type: 'bar'
              },
              xAxis: {
                  categories: name,
              },
              yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  labels: {
                      overflow: 'justify'
                  }
              },
              tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: ' %'
              },
              plotOptions: {
                  bar: {
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  },
                  series: {
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      point: {
                          events: {
                              click: function(event:any){
                                  console.log(event.target.id);
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              series: [{
                  showInLegend: false,
                  data: value,
                  name: 'Demo'
              }]
          };

      }
  );
```

Currently when i click on a bar i could only get the name and its percentage. is there a way to pass in the whole object or at least include the id reference with each data value so i can extract it once clicked?

Comment: check this  http://jsfiddle.net/7044xhdm/

Comment: @Deep3015 THANK YOU!! this what i was looking for. If you post it as an answer i will mark it as the answer - thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.First proper data series has to be form

```
var dataObj=[{id: 1, uuid: "0ff158d7-09a7-41df-81d1-fd3ac752a967",
name: "Example 1", percentage: 34},
{id: 2, uuid: "81aa6eb2-b6fe-4d14-a3ea-f5487b67784a", name: "Example 2", percentage: 0},
{id: 7, uuid: "b7d7fd90-d9af-4a56-aceb-20bfdeda3af4", name: "Example 3", percentage: 12}];

var value=[];
for(var i=0;i<dataObj.length;i++){
value.push({name:dataObj[i].name,y:dataObj[i].percentage,uuid:dataObj[i].uuid,id:dataObj[i].id})
}
console.log(value);
```

2.`PlotOptions` will be

```
plotOptions: {
              bar: {
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: false
                  }
              },
              series: {
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  point: {
                      events: {
                          click: function(event){
                              console.log(event.point.id);
                              console.log(event.point.uuid);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7044xhdm/) demo